# How to directly transfer lambda function logs to new relic

Tags: logging, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I am trying to integrate my lambda function with new relic for logs transfer using this [extension](https://github.com/newrelic/serverless-newrelic-lambda-layers). My serverless.yml code snippet looks like this

```
custom:
  serverlessSsmFetch:
    API_KEY: /aws/parameter/path/to/apiKey
  newRelic:
    linkedAccount: Account Name
    accountId: XXXXXXX
    apiKey: ${self:custom.serverlessSsmFetch.API_KEY}
    enableFunctionLogs: true
    cloudWatchFilter: "*"

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-newrelic-lambda-layers
  - serverless-ssm-fetch
```

But it returns this warning and falls back to using cloudwatch for logs transfer.

```
Warning: Unable to find NR License key for extension validation; falling back to CloudWatch for transport.
Adding NewRelic layer to function1
Warning: Function "function1" already will be handled with provider.layers; skipping.
Warning: No New Relic AWS Lambda integration found for this New Relic linked account and aws account.
```

I have checked the apiKey in the environment variables of the function, it is getting the correct key.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a `USER` key for the API Key? I had the same issue, and it turns out I was using the incorrect API Key type (i.e. `Ingest - License` was not correct).

Comment: We need to use USER key or Ingest-License key then?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using the same **serverless-newrelic-lambda-layers** extension and this works for me:
- Store the config values in AWS Systems Manager > Parameter Store
- Pass SLS environment and get it in serverless.ts (or yml) as below

> ```
> accountId: '${ssm:/${sls:stage}/newrelic-accountId}',
> apiKey: '${ssm:/${sls:stage}/newrelic-api-key}',
> ```